# Is there a GUI SFTP Client that can transfer files between two computers that I can SFTP to?

Tags: windows, sftp

Is there a GUI SFTP Client that can transfer files between two computers that I can SFTP to?

I set up two  virtual machines (happen to be VPSs, e.g. "digitalocean droplets")

Each one runs an SSH server on it.

I have an OpenSSH installation on my computer (happens to have come with cygwin), and I can SSH to a computer from there, and i've generated keys with it. I'm using that for my keys, my keys are fine.

I'm using FileZilla to connect to them (pointing it to my private key.. and my public key is on those computers).

And that's all working fine.

FileZilla can connect to each of them.

I'd like to drag and drop files between them.

But

I can't get one FileZilla window to connect to two different computers, show the files of one computer in one window, the files of the other computer in another window, and drag and drop. The FileZilla GUI window only seems to show the local computer and one remote computer.

FileZilla doesn't have an option to create a new window, so I thought of creating two instances of FileZilla and dragging between them, but I got the message

[image]

This is not pretty to look 'cos the GUIs aren't that succinct, but here's a picture of what I attempted.. I tried dragging a file from one remote computer, to another remote computer, by dragging across FileZilla windows.

[image]

But I got that message of "Drag and drop between different instances of FileZilla has not been implemented yet"

Comment: WS_FTP perhaps  (Progress Software)

Comment: not exactly an SFTP client but i'm gonna try to map drives.. https://sftptogo.com/blog/how-to-map-sftp-as-a-windows-10-drive/

Comment: @John thanks, i'll have a look at it though I see it's a 30 day trial and after that it's about $50 and they ask for a business email so they just assume straight away it's being bought for a business.

Comment: I have WS_FTP. You do not need to be a business to purchase  it ( at least I did not have to be  a business).

Comment: @John yeah i'll just put my email for business email.. but main point is it's not free other than the free trial.

Answer (score 2):

[WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/) allows transferring files via a local temporary copy between different servers.

See [Can I transfer files between two remote servers with WinSCP?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_fxp)

It even has an [extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_synchronize_another_server) that allows synchronizing files between the servers.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 1):

Even if FileZilla allowed drag&drop between instances it would mean that files would be transferred from the one server to your computer and from there to the other server. This is quite inefficient and probably a real bottle neck. Much better if the two servers could connect directly to each other. Means you need to set up the private keys accordingly. Then you could for example use [SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS) on one of your server to mount the other server's files. Now you would see both file systems in one session and you could  drag&drop from one server to the other.

Comment: what if I have 50 servers(virtual machine servers), and I want each one to see aech other one.. Maybe a script with a bunch of SSHFS commands.. so each one has 49/50 mappings..  but maybe there's some way to connect each one to some server (still that'd be an intermediary), but it's neater.. Having each one with 49/50 mappings   I think sysadmins probably do it all the time from their computer in their IT office, though it's within their own LAN. So using their compute to drag a file or files from one person's computer to anothers.

Comment: If you have 50 servers you could connect them all to a vpn and use other file sever protocols (nfs or samba if you like). Or use configuration management like ansible to push things around.